# Services Manager app for windows vista and or windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, services

I would like to know if there is any app for safely management of windows services.
Thank you

Comment: Define "Safely Management"? Like services.msc?

Comment: Well...I think yes. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best management tool for Windows services is in my opinion the one that is built into Windows.  Hit the Windows Key + R on your keyboard to bring up a run command, and then enter "services.msc" to open up the service console.  From the console you can start/stop/enable/disable an service that is currently installed on the OS.

Is there a particular function that you are looking to perform on a service?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the trouble, i was dumb on this one.
And yes, there is one service i want to re-activate, i found it.
Again, thanks.

Comment: You can also traverse to services from control panel.
Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to actualy monitor and/or restart services automatically you might want to check out Service Hawk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm biased, but I created a Windows Services Management Panel called [My Windows Services Panel](http://my-windows-services-panel.garsonix.co.uk/).

It's supposed to be simple and lets you stop and start services. It's aimed at people who need to stop and start the same services regularly. You can choose a list of favourite services and it shows you just these so you don't have to trawl through all the services.

It's open source and isn't doing anything funky in the background, so I think that makes it safe.

Answer (score 0):

There's NSSM
https://nssm.cc/download

And SrvMan, Awesome tool!
https://sysprogs.com/legacy/tools/srvman/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1172801)